# Why does appending a value in a list changes the value in the assigned list too?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = [1]
b = a
a.append(2)
print(b)
-------output--------
[1,2]
```

Can anyone explain me the reason why b value is updated when we update the value of a ???

Comment: `b = a` means you create a reference of a list, not a new list. If you want to create a copy you need to tell python, e.g. `b = a.copy()` otherwise b is just a reference, or lets say a synonym for a.

Comment: `b = a` does not make a *copy* of the list; it just makes a second name for the same list. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: You might want to check out the difference between mutable and immutable data types in Python too! =)

Comment: @TimJim The OP expected `a` to be changed, just not `b`.

Comment: "Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. " (cf. [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html))

Comment: @chepner ah yes, you're right - I just skimmed through on my way past! I had mutable python containers on my mind at the time